# formatting date in Java?

Tags: java, date, format

I need that the returned date string would have the format:

```
"DD/MM/YYYY"
```

i.e. 2 digits for day and month and 4 digits for year.

Example:

```
int day = 11;
int month = 2;
int year = 1997;
```

be returned as

```
"11/02/1997"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your date format is wrong.change

```
"DD/MM/YYYY"
```

to

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Meaning of `d` and `D` is differ same as `y` and `Y`

[Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) about that.

Answer to the next part.

You can use Calender for this

```
 int day = 11;
 int month = 2; // 0th January. 1st February... so on
 int year = 1997;

 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);
 calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,day);

 DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Out put:

```
 11/02/1997
```

You may need to read about [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar  calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(1997, 11, 2);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```